# Change the value of Input field and press enter using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, input, web-crawler

I am trying to collect some information from a web page by changing the value of an input field. But every time I change the value, the webpage **automatically changes** the value of the input box back to the default value. Here is the implementation:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
page = driver.get("https://www.edmunds.com/cars-for-sale-by-owner/")

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("zip")
inputElement.clear()
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("zip")
inputElement.send_keys('23835')
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

How can I change the value and press enter to get the filtered webpage?

**Update!! Solution:**
Change the value to null by `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','')",inputElement)` , then write other logic to send keys. It did not work at first, but now Its working though.

```
def enter_value(zipcode):
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("zip")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','')",inputElement)
    print(inputElement.get_attribute('value'))
    inputElement.clear()
    inputElement.send_keys(zipcode)
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
drive = driver.get("https://www.edmunds.com/cars-for-sale-by-owner/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'zip')))

enter_value(zipcode="23831")
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use ctrl + a  then delete to clear the input field, cause `.clear()` seems like not working consistent.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.edmunds.com/cars-for-sale-by-owner/")
inputElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "zip")))
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
time.sleep(2)
inputElement.send_keys('23835')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.
But when you try to press **Enter** then It reverts back (changes to the previous value).

```inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)```

Comment: well, I tried manually as well, it's reverting to same default value too.

Comment: Even JS does not do nothing `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '23835')", inputElement)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

Comment: It works when you use a function.
I have posted an answer. (I do not know the reason why. I have implemented the same thing but this time, using a function. Now It works)

Comment: I know the method does not mean anything.
but It did not work before but now It is working. And you can have a look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898890/setting-attribute-value-selenium-python
where i got the idea. (driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','')",inputElement). 
Even your answer was not working then though. I think may be this is an issue of their site. By the way Thank you for your answer!